# Android custom component doesn't retain value on orientation change

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a layout that uses TextView and a custom control I created that combine a TextView and two buttons for an integer up/down control. The TextView retains its value when the device is rotated, I'm calling the save/restore instance state.  I'm not capturing any values as the device retains the values.  However, this is not the case for my custom component.

Is there something I need to implement in a custom control so when the device orientation changes it retains the values like the native controls do?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you override [`onSaveInstanceState()`/`onRestoreInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState())? It's hard to know what you would need to save/restore, that would depend on what your custom control does.

Comment: Yes, I did override those methods and my native controls do persist values but the custom components do not.

Comment: Do your custom components have a non-default id? If not, the default behavior of Activity would be to skip them. You either need to give each custom view an id >= 0 or else override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` in your activity to call on them explicitly.

Comment: I do assign an @+id/somevalue to each use of the custom component in a layout.  Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw `android:configChanges="orientation"` into your `activity` tags in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent your activity from being destroyed and recreated as Haphazard suggests, and this is probably the best solution.

If you don't want to do that, then you need override the following three methods:

- [`isSaveEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isSaveEnabled%28%29) (override to return `true`)
- [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29)
- [`onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Parcelable%29)

Consult the documentation (such as it is) for how to do this. There's also an example of how it's done [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/android-basics-managing-activity-states-part-i/). The view will need a non-default ID to have it's `onSaveInstanceState()` called or else you'll also need to override [`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) in your activity.

Comment: Thanks Ted.  The above so far has not worked.  It must have something to do with having a class extend LinearLayout which is what I'm doing in the creation of the custom control (linear layout, horizontal, three controls).